Cassandra Reads Data from another node while it shouldn't
Summary
I have created a scenario with 3 nodes where 1 node is out of sync with other nodes and when I connect to that node, I see that it is retrieving data which it shouldn't have because it is reading the data from another node (I believe that the node which I'm connected to using a driver, is the coordinator node).
I don't know what am I missing and Why is Cassandra exactly doing this?
Steps:

Create a cluster of 3 nodes with default settings and no auth, using docker and cassandra version 4.1.5 and using CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH=GossipingPropertyFileSnitch

docker run --name cass1 -d -p 19001:9042 --network=casscluster -e CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME=chat -e CASSANDRA_DC=dc1 -e CASSANDRA_RACK=rack1 -e CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH=GossipingPropertyFileSnitch -e CASSANDRA_SEEDS="cass1,cass2" -e CASSANDRA_LISTEN_ADDRESS="cass1" -e CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS="cass1" cassandra:4.1.5
docker run --name cass2 -d -p 19002:9042 --network=casscluster -e CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME=chat -e CASSANDRA_DC=dc1 -e CASSANDRA_RACK=rack1 -e CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH=GossipingPropertyFileSnitch -e CASSANDRA_SEEDS="cass1,cass2" -e CASSANDRA_LISTEN_ADDRESS="cass2" -e CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS="cass2" cassandra:4.1.5
docker run --name cass3 -d -p 19003:9042 --network=casscluster -e CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME=chat -e CASSANDRA_DC=dc1 -e CASSANDRA_RACK=rack1 -e CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH=GossipingPropertyFileSnitch -e CASSANDRA_SEEDS="cass1,cass2" -e CASSANDRA_LISTEN_ADDRESS="cass3" -e CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS="cass3" cassandra:4.1.5


In every node, disabled hinted handoff from yml and restarted nodes (checked each node with nodetool statushandoff to make sure hinted_hand_off is disabled)

nodetool statushandoff
Hinted handoff is not running


Create keyspace with replication factor of 3.

create keyspace testak WITH REPLICATION = {
    'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy',
    'dc1' : 3
    };


Create table and also disable speculative_retry (so that it does not read from other nodes if the query takes too much time)

create table testak.mooz
(
    userid int,
    chatid int,
    name   text,
    primary key (userid, chatid)
);
alter table testak.mooz with speculative_retry = 'none';


Stop node 3
Insert in node 1

insert into testak.mooz (userid, chatid) values (1, 1);
insert into testak.mooz (userid, chatid) values (2, 1);
insert into testak.mooz (userid, chatid) values (3, 1);
insert into testak.mooz (userid, chatid) values (4, 1);
insert into testak.mooz (userid, chatid) values (5, 1);
insert into testak.mooz (userid, chatid) values (6, 1);
insert into testak.mooz (userid, chatid) values (7, 1);
insert into testak.mooz (userid, chatid) values (8, 1);
insert into testak.mooz (userid, chatid) values (9, 1);
insert into testak.mooz (userid, chatid) values (10, 1);


Start node 3
Use external cqlsh to connect to node 3
docker run  --name cqlsh --rm -it --network=casscluster nuvo/docker-cqlsh cqlsh cass3 9042 --cqlversion=3.4.6
Set consistency one
CONSISTENCY ONE
Tracing on
TRACING ON
Select 1 row
select * from testak.mooz where userid = 1 and chatid = 1;

Because the replication factor is 3 and I have 3 nodes, I expect that all nodes assume that they have all the data and don't need to query the data from another node, but by issuing the query multiple times, I see that sometimes requests goes to other nodes and actually retrieves data which it shouldn't because node 3 has inconsistency and does not have the real record data.

Here's a screen shot where it shows it is retrieving data from another node.
Note: Most of the times (~90%) it does not read data from another node.
Update
Later I set logging level using nodetool setlogginglevel org.apache.cassandra ALL and looked at debug.log, and here's the log when cassandra decides to read data from another node:
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2024-07-18 08:47:01,109 CoordinatorWarnings.java:49 - CoordinatorTrackWarnings.init()
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2024-07-18 08:47:01,110 Dispatcher.java:164 - Received: QUERY select * from testak.mooz where userid = 1 and chatid = 1; [pageSize = 100] at consistency ONE, v=4/v4
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2024-07-18 08:47:01,110 QueryProcessor.java:251 - Process SelectStatement[aggregationSpecFactory=<null>,bindVariables=[],isReversed=false,limit=<null>,..(truncated long log line)
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2024-07-18 08:47:01,111 ReadCallback.java:90 - Blockfor is 1; setting up requests to org.apache.cassandra.locator.ReplicaPlan$SharedForTokenRead@74da23a8
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2024-07-18 08:47:01,111 MessagingService.java:401 - cass3/172.20.0.4:7000 sending READ_REQ to 2781@/172.20.0.3:7000
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2024-07-18 08:47:01,111 AbstractReadExecutor.java:226 - Decided not to speculate as 9223372036854775807 > 5000000
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2024-07-18 08:47:01,122 CoordinatorWarnings.java:80 - CoordinatorTrackWarnings.done() with state {}
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2024-07-18 08:47:01,122 CoordinatorWarnings.java:61 - CoordinatorTrackWarnings.reset()
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2024-07-18 08:47:01,122 Dispatcher.java:214 - Responding: ROWS [userid(testak, mooz), org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.Int32Type][chatid(testak, mooz), org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.Int32Type][name(testak, mooz), org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type]
 | 1 | 1 | null
---, v=4/v4

But when data is read from the node itself, instead of the line with sending READ_REQ, I see this line:
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2024-07-18 08:47:49,248 EndpointMessagingVersions.java:67 - Assuming current protocol version for cass3/172.20.0.4:7000
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2024-07-18 08:47:49,248 AbstractReadExecutor.java:158 - reading data locally

Update2
Running nodetool getendpoints testak mooz 1 on cass3:
172.20.0.3
172.20.0.4
172.20.0.2

nodetool status testak:
Datacenter: dc1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load        Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  172.20.0.3  227.48 KiB  16      100.0%            2a4a84a4-1894-488a-8661-680cf818384b  rack1
UN  172.20.0.4  232.56 KiB  16      100.0%            9ed9d3f6-13e0-424f-bf52-1bd359d8a26e  rack1
UN  172.20.0.2  281.54 KiB  16      100.0%            68de8980-ab63-4745-85b1-6b98636ea9af  rack1

nodetool describecluster:
Cluster Information:
        Name: chat
        Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
        DynamicEndPointSnitch: enabled
        Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
        Schema versions:
                629e0d12-c942-3eeb-bce3-5616a291ae90: [172.20.0.4, 172.20.0.2, 172.20.0.3]

Stats for all nodes:
        Live: 3
        Joining: 0
        Moving: 0
        Leaving: 0
        Unreachable: 0

Data Centers:
        dc1 #Nodes: 3 #Down: 0

Database versions:
        4.1.5: [172.20.0.4:7000, 172.20.0.2:7000, 172.20.0.3:7000]

Keyspaces:
        system_auth -> Replication class: SimpleStrategy {replication_factor=1}
        testak -> Replication class: NetworkTopologyStrategy {dc1=3}
        system_distributed -> Replication class: SimpleStrategy {replication_factor=3}
        system_traces -> Replication class: SimpleStrategy {replication_factor=2}
        system_schema -> Replication class: LocalStrategy {}
        system -> Replication class: LocalStrategy {}


Unfortunately, your base assumption is incorrect.
While cqlsh forces the coordinator to be the node it connects to, it does not guarantee that it reads the data from the coordinator. The coordinator can still decide to fetch the data from a different node. It's the snitch that decides which node the coordinator sends this request to.
You are using the dynamic snitch which distributes requests based on read latency and routes request to the most healthy node.
There is a good reason Cassandra behaves this way. If the Coordinator is not feeling well, it shouldn't take the request even if it is technically fewer network trips. The dynamic snitch would instead send the request to the node with the quickest latency, thereby spreading the load evenly throughout the cluster.

I actually cloned the cassandra repository and by reading the code, I achieved the same conclusion as you, but I was not sure and needed a confirmation from someone else. Thank you.

This is what I found in the code:
(some part of the stacktrace where it was running the query)
StorageProxy.fetchRows:2074
AbstractReadExecutor.getReadExecutor:198
ReplicaPlans.forRead:773
ReplicaLayout.forTokenReadLiveSorted:358
and the comment for method forTokenReadLiveSorted is:
/**

@return the read layout for a token - this includes only live natural replicas, i.e. those that are not pending
and not marked down by the failure detector. these are reverse sorted by the badness score of the configured snitch
*/

